# Performing analysis of covariance with python/scipy/statsmodel

Tags: scipy, statsmodels

Could anyone please help in providing an example showing how ANCOVA (analysis of covariance) can be done in scipy/statsmodel, with python?

I am not sure if I am asking too much, but a quick search showed me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916760/ancova-in-python-with-scipy-numpy-stats) which is not informative enough for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Statsmodels uses the linear model, OLS, to estimate ANOVA. So, having additional continuous regressors as in ANCOVA does not change the analysis.

Here are a few links to the relevant documentation

Anova helper functions and examples for ANCOVA interactions
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_interactions.html

using formulas to create the design matrix
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/example_formulas.html

the core OLS model
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html

Comment: Thanks for these, #user333700. The site in the ANCOVA interaction link has changed and I see a non-ANCOVA categorical interaction link at http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/categorical_interaction_plot.html and there are now interaction examples with GLM at http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm_formula.html

Answer (score 0):

[on geeks](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-perform-an-ancova-in-python)

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

# Define the data for the ANCOVA
df = pd.DataFrame({'dependent_variable' : [8, 7, 9, 11, 10, 12, 14, 13, 15, 16],
   'group' : ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"],
    'covariate' : [20, 30, 40, 30, 40, 50, 40, 50, 60, 70]})

# Perform the ANCOVA
model = ols('dependent_variable ~ group + covariate', data=df).fit()

# Print the summary of the model
print(model.summary())
```

[assumptions for ANCOVA](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00474/full) - N.B. belongs to **General Linear Models** (*vs Generalized Linear Models* - The general linear model requires that the response variable follows the normal distribution whilst the generalized linear model is an extension of the general linear model that allows the specification of models whose response variable follows different distributions.)

[ANOVA & ANCOVA differ](https://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/942/q3/ancova_142.pdf)

> Analysis of covariance (ANCOVA) is a statistical procedure that allows
> you to include both categorical and continuous variables in a single
> model. ANCOVA assumes that the regression coefficients are homogeneous
> (the same) across the categorical variable. Violation of this
> assumption can lead to incorrect conclusions.

[correct data for ANCOVA](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2015.00474/full) - centered

[e.g. how to handle interactions of continuous & categorical vars](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/library/spss-libraryhow-do-i-handle-interactions-of-continuous-andcategorical-variables/)

> in ANCOVA it is
> important to test the homogeneity of regression assumption, and if
> this assumption is violated we then need to estimate models that have
> separate slopes across groups.